# Unit Testing jasmine

Tags: jasmine

Am trying to write a spec as below but am not able to run it,below are the sample files i used
**Sample.js**

```
(function (app) {

    var SimpleController = function ($scope) {

        $scope.x = 3;
        $scope.y = 4;
        $scope.doubleIt = function () {
            $scope.x *= 2;
            $scope.y *= 2;
        };
    };

    app.controller("SimpleController", 
             ["$scope", SimpleController]);

}(angular.module("myApp")));
```

Spec.js

```
describe("myApp", function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    describe("SimpleController", function() {

        var scope;
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller("SimpleController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it("should double the numbers", function() {
            scope.doubleIt();
            expect(scope.x).toBe(6);
        });
    });
});
```

I have below js files 
- jasmine.js

- jasmine-html.js
- angular.js
- angular-mocks.js
- sample.js

While running the spec it displays
Error: No module: myApp
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'doubleIt': object is null or undefined

Kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: do you have reference path on your spec.js file pointing to simple.js??

Comment: Yes, i have reference path of simple.js in specrunner.html

Comment: you also need to have a reference path in your spec.js file referencing to your sample.js file like : 
                             `/// <reference path="sample.js" />`